# Excel VBA: Writing data to cells in non-contiguous columns

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to minimize the calls I make to the Excel OM by writing data to non contiguous (column) cells in one call. Something like this:

```
Public Sub TestNoncontiguousWrite()

    Dim arr(1, 3) As Integer
    arr(0, 0) = 10
    arr(0, 1) = 11
    arr(0, 2) = 12

    Range("A1,B1,E1").Value = arr

End Sub
```

However, when I do this, I end up with the following:

[image: actual output]

Whereas I'm aiming for the following result:

[image: desired output]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array and destination range is of different shape.
One way is to iterate through it by looping or you can try below:

```
Public Sub TestNoncontiguousWrite()
    Dim arr(4) As Variant
    arr(0) = 10
    arr(1) = 11
    arr(2) = ""
    arr(3) = ""
    arr(4) = 12
    Range("A1:E1").Value = arr
End Sub
```

This way, you create same shape and dimension array with reference to your Range.
If however you cannot overwrite what's in C and D, you have to loop

```
Public Sub TestNoncontiguousWrite2()
    Dim arr(0, 2) As Integer
    arr(0, 0) = 10
    arr(0, 1) = 11
    arr(0, 2) = 12

    Dim c As Range, i as long: i = 0
    For Each c in Range("A1,B1,E1")
        c = arr(0, i): i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

This way, you write each element of your array in your target cells. HTH.

Comment: So there is no way of just writing to non contiguous cells without either writing to cells in between of using a loop (which involves the original number of OM calls)?

Comment: @PatMustard AFAIK yes.